# Passing HTML5 from Adobe Flex

Tags: java, html, apache-flex

I would like to ask a question about web technologies. We are working on a web application and using Adobe Flex and its facilities. As you know, with a Flex project, we are able to connect a server and use containers stored on the RAM (may be Java containers) instead directly retrieving information from database, by using blazeds. We now thinking about leaving Flex and start HTML5. However, we do not have much information about the HTML5, my first question is whether there is a connector like BlazeDs helps us to communicate with Java objcets on the server on HTML5, or is there another way to do this? Does this matter refer to Cloud Computing? And is there any MVC framework for HTML5? What do you suggest us to about passing HTML5 from Adobe Flex?
Regards

Comment: You're making a decision to switch to HTML5 while you don't know the first thing about it? I would suggest to take a step back, do some research first and then make an argumented decision on which technology to choose (other than: "my customer has heard that Flex is dead and HTML5 is the holy grail")

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need one more reputation to accept/reject answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar situation, switching from Flex to HTML5. I would highly recommend using [Sencha](http://sencha.com) for your HTML5 app. They have a number of different options for getting information from a server, similar to how you are using BlazeDS. They also have an excellent HTML mobile framework if that is what you are after. What I did was to simply take the Java objects I was normally sending through flex and serialize them to JSON, which can easily be read in using Javascript or using the built in classes and methods provided by Sencha. There are a number of Java libraries that will do the Java to JSON conversion for you. I have personally used and like [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Answer (score 2):

In HTML / xScript you can get what you need from your server using XMLHTTPRequest or simply passing a FORM with whatever params you need. Some examples here: http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxxmlhttprequest.php

Using ajax it doesn't really matter what's on the back end - java, PHP, etc. Whatever the server has to offer will work.

@RIAStar has it right - both languages will get you there. Just be sure where 'there' is.